# ZoomCharts NetChart: Multiple links with the same ID will be merged warning message

Tags: javascript, zoomcharts, netchart

I'm working on some user's information to represent data in a network chart. And data nodes/links are loading dynamically.

When child node data is loaded then child node-link info is replacing parent node-link information. That is giving me a problem.

Now I'm trying to find a way, why which if any two nodes link is already loaded then that link should not override with the new link. That means the new link will remove.

I'm attaching a screenshot of the message which I'm getting when data is loading.

[image]

I searched regarding this on ZoomChart documentation and also on google. But I didn't find any solution.

Answer (score 0):

The link should have the same data regardless if it's child or parent that's triggering loading of that. If the link content is different based on the direction, then sounds like you should have two links e.g.:

```
{id: "child-parent", from: "child", to: "parent", extra: {someProperty: 1}},
{id: "parent-child", from: "parent", to: "child", extra: {someProperty: 2}}
```

You should not have the following:

```
{id: "parent-child", from: "child", to: "parent", extra: {someProperty: 1}},
{id: "parent-child", from: "parent", to: "child", extra: {someProperty: 2}}
```

as this will make it impossible to understand how the link should be treated.

Also, use [multiLinkProcessor](https://zoomcharts.com/developers/en/net-chart/api-reference/settings.html#doc_filters.multilinkProcessor) to combine multiple links if necessary.